# Calling service method from a directive template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Let's say I have a **directive**:

```
<component>
   <img ng-src='{{something}}' />
</component>
```

defined as:

```
app.directive("component", function() {
    return {
        scope: {},
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        template: "<a href='' ng-click='MyService.doThings()' ng-transclude></a>"
    }
});
```

Despite all my efforts, I fail to understand how to accomplish two tasks:

1. How do I access the inner image source path?
2. How can I pass this path to service `MyService`? (think of a lightbox wrapper)

**Update with solution:**

```
app.directive("component", function(LightboxService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true,
        template: "<a href='' ng-click='lb()' ng-transclude></a>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.lb = function () {
                var src = $(element).find("img").attr("src");
                LightboxService.show(src);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. You can access the source path either by binding it to your controller scope or from a link method using attributes.
2. You can not access Service from a template. You should inject your service into a controller and define a function in $scope to call from the template.

Check your directive below:

```
app.directive("component", function() {
    return {
        scope: {
          ngSrc: "@", //Text Binding
        },
        controller: function($scope, MyService) {
           $scope.doThings = function() {
               MyService.doThings();
           }
        },
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        template: "<a href='{{ng-src}}' ng-click='doThings' ng-transclude></a>"
    }
});
```

You can learn more about directives with isolated scope here:
https://umur.io/angularjs-directives-using-isolated-scope-with-attributes/

Comment: I've tried it with a link method, it works; if I define a method in the inner scope that calls the service method, works too :) seems the correct way to go, thanks! (I've included my solution in the post)